# org-notmuch error: user-error: No method for storing a link from this buffer

Tags: org-mode, notmuch

i have added the

`(require 'org-notmuch)`

to my config and can verify it loads by seeing the notmuch link type in my org mode links.

yet when i try to issue `org-store-link` in a notmuch buffer i always get the error

`user-error: No method for storing a link from this buffer`

any clue?

Comment: Org doesn't need org-notmuch to display the notmuch link type, it simply displays `[[link][desc]]` as link even it doesn't know how to open/store the type of the link. You can use `M-: (featurep 'org-notmuch)` to know if org-notmuch is loaded.

Comment: thx. so indeed org-much is loaded yet i still get the error when i try to copy the current link in a notmuch buffer

Answer (score 1):

I found org-notmuch.el in the contrib/lisp directory of the orgmode git repository.  I encountered this error when that git repo was out of sync with my system's org / notmuch.  Updating my git checkout resolved the issue.